# Bash: Find and replace text strings

Tags: bash, grep, sed, bash-scripting

I figured this would be easy, but I'm overlooking something simple:

I have a text file called `test`. It contains, for example, the string `Alfred Hitchcock`. I want to replace this with `Alfred\ Hitchcock`.

I figured this would do it:

```
grep -r1 ' ' /path/to/test | xargs sed -i 's/ /\ /g'
```

But it tells me:

```
sed: can't read Alfred: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Hitchcock: No such file or directory
```

Not quite sure what's going on. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve with the grep command. Do you want to replace spaces in all files inside a directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `grep` at all:

```
sed -i 's/ /\ /g' /path/to/test
```

This will escape all spaces in the file. To escape only on some strings, see Guru's answer.

Now, if you want to do that on all files which contain a space character in a given directory:

```
grep -rl ' ' /path/to/test/dir | xargs sed -i 's/ /\ /g'
```

which is, now I realize, identical to your command line, **except the char after `-r`, which should be a lowercase `L`**.

*(Note: I'm assuming GNU tools are being used.)*

Comment: I'm nost sure if all `sed(1)` handle `-i`; use a temporary file if your's doesn't: `sed 's/ /\\ /g' /path/to/test > tmpfile; mv tmpfile /path/to/test`

Comment: Since grep's `-r` flag is being used in the OP, I believe GNU tools are being used. But that's a good point.

Comment: If you're new to sed and you use `-i` I would suggest doing `-i.orig` or something distinguishable, it makes a copy first (just in case you make a mistake in the sed command!)

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
sed -i 's/Alfred Hitchcock/Alfred\\ Hitchcock/' /path/to/test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the grep command by itself to see what's happening.

It will print something like

```
/path/to/test/test:Alfred Hitchcock
```

When piping this to xargs, it will attempt to execute

```
sed -i 's/ /\ /g' /path/to/test/test:Alfred
sed -i 's/ /\ /g' Hitchcock
```