# how to echo text into a file from the CLI to ammend a variable in the file?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

using Centos7

e.g

```
vi test.txt
```

test.txt contains the following information

```
x=100
y=200
z=300
```

I want to put a command into the CLI such as `echo x=250 >> test.txt` but instead of `x=250` being added to the bottom of the file, I want it to replace `x=100` with `x=250`

any help on hwo to tackle this is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you ask for "how to echo" when you actually want to replace texts. There are already so many duplicates which can easily be find within the first google page [Find and replace text within a file using commands](https://askubuntu.com/q/20414/253474), [Find and replace text strings](https://superuser.com/q/548995/241386), [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?(https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/44425), [Replacing string in a script using sed](https://superuser.com/q/778344/241386)...

Comment: echo then amend was my train of thought, I did search on google but was obviously using the wrong language. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`'s inline replacement feature for this:

Like:

```
sed -i 's/x=.*$/x=250/g' test.txt
```

For example:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ more test.txt
x=100
y=200
z=300
mtak@rubiks:~$ sed -i 's/x=.*$/x=250/g' test.txt
mtak@rubiks:~$ more test.txt
x=250
y=200
z=300
```

Comment: @davetherave I'm glad it does, please mark it as an answer by clicking the green check mark on the left, so it's easier for posterity to find (and give me a few rep in the process). See https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers